# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages when trying to install yaws 1.98 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, apt, yaws, package-management

I get the following errors when trying to install yaws 1.98 on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
bash$ sudo apt-get install yaws
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
yaws : Depends: erlang-yaws (>= 1.92-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Perhaps the answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/223237/22015) or [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/363200/22015) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're holding broken packages, you might want to try the [advice provided here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) to fix that problem, and then try again to [install Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/configuration.yaws).

Answer (score 0):

aptitude's dependency resolver is more suitable for interactive dependency resolution than apt's dependency resolver. aptitude remembers which packages were explicitly requested and which packages were only installed due to dependencies. aptitude will make a series of recommendations and give you a choice of possible dependency resolutions.

Install aptitude:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Use aptitude for interactive resolution of `you have held broken packages`  errors with a command of the form:

```
sudo aptitude install package-name
```

Comment: after I run ```sudo apt install aptitude```, it shows again: "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: Use aptitude aptitude's interactive dependency resolution functionality to solve the problem. Sometimes you need to use aptitude's interactive dependency resolution functionality iteratively to correct problems one at a time until the package management issue is resolved.